# having errors while trying to switch between sections on portfolio website

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a javascript function that will allow me to toggle between sections of my portfolio website, but the code starts crashing after a while.

It works for a moment and then gives me error saying "app.js:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'className') at HTMLDivElement. (app.js:10:53)".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPhPZ.jpg) (here is the pic of the problem)
Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Here goes the code:

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
const sectBtns = document.querySelectorAll(".controlls");
const sectBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".control");
const allSections = document.querySelector('.main-content');

function PageTransitions() {
    for (let i = 0; i < sectBtn.length; i++) {
        sectBtn[i]. addEventListener("click", function() {
            let currentBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn');
            currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn','');
            this.className += 'active-btn';
        })
    }

    allSections.addEventListener('click', (e)=> {
        const id = e.target.dataset.id;
        if (id) {
            sectBtns.forEach((btn) => {
                btn.classList.remove('active')
            })

            e.target.classList.add('active')

            sections.forEach((section)=> {
                section.classList.remove('active')
            })

            const element = document.getElementById(id);
            element.classList.add('active');
        }
    }) 
}

PageTransitions();
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>Portfolio</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/styles.css">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/25c3cf235c.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>
        <body class="main-content">
            <header class="section sec1 header active" id ="home">
                
            </header>
            <main>
                <section class="section sec2 about" id ="about"></section>
                <section class="section sec3 portfolio" id ="portfolio"></section>
                <section class="section sec4 blogs" id ="blogs"></section>
                <section class="section sec5 contact" id ="contact"></section>
            </main> 

            <div class="controlls">
                <div class="control control-1 active-btn" data-id ="home">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-house-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="control control-2 " data-id ="about">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="control control-3 " data-id ="portfolio">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-briefcase"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="control control-4 " data-id ="blogs">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-newspaper"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="control control-5 " data-id ="contact">
                    <i class="fa-solid fa-envelope"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

            <script src = "app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style: none;
}

:root {
    --color-primary: #191d2b;
    --color-secondary: #27AE60;
    --color-white: #FFFFFF;
    --color-black: #000;
    --color-grey0: #f8f8f8;
    --color-grey-1: #dbe1e8;
    --color-grey-2: #b2becd;
    --color-grey-3: #6c7983;
    --color-grey-4: #454e56;
    --color-grey-5: #2a2e35;
    --color-grey-6: #12181b;
    --br-sm-2: 14px;
    --box-shadow-1: 0 3px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

body {
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: var(--color-white );
    transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
}

header {
    height: 100vh;
    color: var(--color-white);
    overflow: hidden;
}

section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 3rem 18rem;
}

.section {
    transform: translateY(-100%) scale(0);
    transition: all .4 ease-in-out;
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
}

.sec1 {
    display: none;
    transform: translateV(0) scale(1);
    background-color: rgb(26, 22, 50);
}

.sec2 {
    display: none;
    transform: translateV(0) scale(1);
    background-color: slateblue;
}

.sec3 {
    display: none;
    transform: translateV(0) scale(1);
    background-color: rgb(127, 123, 151);
}
.sec4 {
    display: none;
    transform: translateV(0) scale(1);
}

.sec5 {
    display: none;
    transform: translateV(0) scale(1);
}

.controlls {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    top: 50%;
    right: 3%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    .active-btn {
        background-color: var(--color-secondary) !important;
        transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
        i {
            color: var(--color-white) !important;
        }
    }
    .control {
        padding: 1rem;
        cursor: pointer;
        background-color: var(--color-grey-4);
        width: 55px;
        height: 55px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        margin: .7rem 0;
        box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-1);
        i {
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            color: var(--color-grey-2);
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `currentBtn[0]` - it's probably undefined as the error tells you

Comment: I followed a youtube tutorial so I'm not sure why it is not working

Comment: to find out, use `console.log` ... anyway *I followed a youtube tutorial* - wasn't a very good one with the way they manipulate `.className` - but that's not your issue, your issue is that `document.querySelectorAll('.active-btn')` returns an empty list (perhaps)

Comment: For about 4 to 5 button clicks, the code works fine, but then it stops working. Why is that happening?

Comment: because the code is over complicated ... it can break after 1 click ... click on the green circle, next click is broken

Comment: So are any ways I can toggle between sections without it giving me errors?

Answer (score -1):

```
currentBtn[0].className = currentBtn[0].className.replace('active-btn',''); //error because className is for react development . and basically here you only want to remove a class from the element and add another element.


        

currentBtn[0].classList.remove("active-btn")
currentBtn[0].classList.add("your new class" write here);
```

Comment: would still fail when `currentBtn[0]` is `undefined`

Comment: how can I define it?

Comment: you can't ... but you can guard against the error `if (currentBtn[0]) currentBtn[0].classList.remove("active-btn")`

Comment: @JaromandaX currentBtn[0] will be undefined . then you can use try catch block to prevent error and do some more action

Comment: or a simple `if` as above

Comment: yes that will be more flexible

Comment: so what you're saying is, you've just shown a different way of manipulating the class of the elements, without actually addressing the issue at all